# Clearing the XHR Resource List in Chrome's Debugger

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, debugging

I'm a semi-recent convert (from Firefox/Firebug) for my day to day development.  One of the features I use daily is the debugging feature that keeps track of a page's XHR requests.

Resources -> XHR

In the left pane you get a list of URLs that have been requested via "ajax", and clicking on them will bring up their request properties in the right column.

Short of refreshing the page, is there a way to clear this list of resources?  I find when I'm doing debugging I often need to to repeat the same same in-page ajax request multiple times.  Eventually this list gets long enough that it's hard to keep track of requests.

I know that the most recent request is always at the bottom, but I keep finding myself not realizing another request has been inserted, or accidentally clicking on the second-to-last request.  I'd like to clear out this list without refreshing the page.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a way. Please file a bug in http://crbug.com/new and I will properly cc the team to look at it :) Actually today, I had the similar issue.

The Inspector is ungoing heavy changes, as you have seen. There is currently many stuff that needs to be implemented such as [clearing cache](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=8742), clearing screens, etc. But its getting there :)

So please submit a bug report for that and let me know the bug number.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll try to get to writing up a proper bug report.

Comment: Cool, let me know once you add one, I will add the proper users to take a look.